# UITextView HTML Content With Custom Font and Size

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I've done a lot of search and can't figure out what the correct method to add html content in UITextView. Following is my code. It's not setting correct font type.

```
let htmlProfileString = "<html><head><style>body {font-family:\"SFProText-Regular\";font-size: 16px;color: #FFFFFF;text-decoration:none;}</style></head><body>" +
                        "This is content"
                        + "</body></head></html>"

                    let htmlData = NSString(string: htmlProfileString).data(using: String.Encoding.unicode.rawValue)

                    let options = [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html]

                    let attributedString = try! NSAttributedString(data: htmlData!, options: options, documentAttributes: nil)
                    self.textView.attributedText = attributedString
```

Answer (score 3):

To use the "system" San Francisco font, use `-apple-system`:

```
    let htmlProfileString = "<html><head><style>body {font-family:\"-apple-system\";font-size: 16px;color: #FFFFFF;text-decoration:none;}</style></head><body>" +
        "This is content"
        + "</body></head></html>"
```

You can also use other css font stylings with:

```
font: -apple-system-body 
font: -apple-system-headline 
font: -apple-system-subheadline 
font: -apple-system-caption1 
font: -apple-system-caption2 
font: -apple-system-footnote 
font: -apple-system-short-body 
font: -apple-system-short-headline 
font: -apple-system-short-subheadline 
font: -apple-system-short-caption1 
font: -apple-system-short-footnote 
font: -apple-system-tall-body
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of this. Where can I find more info on this? What is the equivalent of SFProText-Regular?

Comment: Lots of references around the web... I assume -apple-system-body would be equivalent to SFProText-Regular

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want your `textView` to be editable, replace it with a `webView`.

If you do so, you can load your html inside webView with the following method:

```
func loadHTMLString(_ string: String, 
        baseURL: URL?)
```

For further reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview/1617979-loadhtmlstring

Comment: The content is not coming from URL.

Comment: it doesn't have to, it is optional, set it to nil like: 
webView.loadHTMLString("<html><body><p>This is content.</p></body></html>", baseURL: nil)

Comment: It's again comes down to same issue which I started my question with - formatting html content. I'm already doing it as you can see in my question. So whether it's UITextView or Webview it's same html string I'm going to create and display.